# Edge not caching when Vary: Accept-Language is present

Tags: javascript, http-headers, microsoft-edge, cache-control

Using JavaScript, I'm calling a rest API that returns the following headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=60
Content-Length:20
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 15 Aug 2016 21:01:56 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Vary:Accept-Language
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

This get cached by Chrome/Firefox/Safari correctly on subsequent calls, but in Edge nothing gets cached. If I stop sending the `Vary:Accept-Language` header, then it gets cached, but the result is that if a different language is passed to Accept-Language then it returns the (wrong) cached content.

Am I missing something to make Edge cache it?